# Неправильная работа input radio кнопок

Tags: html, css

Проблема с работой input'ов. Создал так называемые табы, добавил контента. Всё работает. После, нужно было сделать обводку снизу блоков а-ля такие

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал сделать обводку самим пунктам, но появились разрывы самой линии. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Было принято решение внести все кнопки в `div`, и для самого элемента `div` задать `border-bottom`.
Но тут загвоздка. После вознесения `input-radio` вместе с `label` в `div` перестали работать кнопки, как задумывалось, да и в целом контент блоков просто перестал отображаться, вместо того чтоб отображаться в зависимости от выбранной кнопки.

Как возобновить работу input'ов?

Решением так же может быть вариант реализации обводки для пунктов выбора.

https://jsfiddle.net/uz51a3ds/2/

Answer (score 1):

1. Код лучше добавлять сюда в сниппет, а не совать на сторонние ресурсы.
2. Термин "вознесение" в контексте верстки вижу первый раз в жизни. Что он означает?
3. После оборачивания блоков с радиокнопками в `<div>` у вас, разумеется, перестал работать стиль `#tab-btn-1:checked~#content-1` и аналогичные. Ибо оператор `~` в
   конструкции `A ~ B` действует на все `B`, идущие ПОСЛЕ `A` НА ТОМ ЖЕ УРОВНЕ вложенности - а у вас `B` на уровень выше.

Предлагаю выкинуть див .tabus и вернуть кнопки в .tabs. И увеличить им паддинги. Если же бордер нужен во всю ширину, задавайте его дивам с контентом.

П.С. Правильно пишется "Choice".